# convert sqlalchemy model or marshmallow schema to avro

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, avro, marshmallow

We want the authority of our avro schema to be our sqlalchemy model, which itself explicitly defines the database schema. We would like to generate an avro schema from the sqlalchemy model itself. Alternatively, it would be easy enough to generate avro schema from a marshmallow schema, since marshmallow already has a bunch of build in compatibility with sqlalchemy.

Unfortunately we haven't been able to find much in the way of libraries which can help us with this. Is anyone aware of a library which will generate avro schema from sqlalchemy models or marshmallow schemas? It seems like something which should already exist and we don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tool. It generates Avro schemas from either .csv or right from relational databases.
https://github.com/romaanankin/avro-schema-manager